# Python virtualenvironment can't find packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, virtualenv

When i `run python -m pip install {package}` inside the virtual environment i created with `python -m venv env` the package is installed inside the env/Lib folder, however when i want to use the package the venv interpreter can't find the package. For example I installed ipykernel, but when I try to run a cell inside Visual Studio code I get a message saying I have to install ipykernel and even if I accept this message and install it again I keep getting the message that I have to install ipykernel.

I already tried deleting all my versions of python and reinstalling python I also tried to set the global target of python to my library folder `python pip config set global.target {path to venv Library}`

I am using python 3.8.0 which is the only python installed on my pc. I also have windows 10 and my editor is visual studio code. Please help.

If I run `python -m pip freeze requirements` inside my enviroment nothing happens. When I `run python -m pip freeze requirements` outside my environment I get a list of all installed packages

Comment: Have you tried activating your virtual environment? e.g. `source venv/bin/activate` and then pip installing in that?

Comment: @jwjhdev there is no module named pip3. I uninstalled all my older versions of python and only installed python 3.8.0

Comment: @Bas yes my virtual enviroment is active

Comment: You also need to tell your IDE (VS Code) to use the virtual environment. Activating it in a shell does not mean the IDE is using it. [This article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) may help.

Comment: I have selected my venv as interpreter for VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Please enter the command "*`pip show ipykernel`*" in the terminal of VS Code to check whether this module is included in this environment. (It checks whether the installation location of the module is consistent with the Python environment displayed in the lower left corner of VSCode.)

[image]

If the terminal shows that there is no such module, please open a new VS Code terminal(shortcut key: Ctrl+Shift+`), it will automatically enter the environment displayed in the lower left corner of VSCode.